# How to decompose the intercept of a linear regression?

Tags: regression, econometrics, decomposition

**Problem**
I'm given a [linear regression model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) I need to to obtain the decomposition of the intercept coefficient in the form of

$$ \hat{\beta_1} = \beta_1 + \sum c_i u_i$$

where $c_i = 1/n - a_i\bar{X}$ and $a_i = \frac{(X_i - \bar{X})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2}$
**Note**, $\beta_1$ is the **intercept**.

**Issues**
I don't really understand how the estimated intercept $\hat{\beta_1}$ relates to the true intercept $\beta_1$.

Comment: This looks like homework. Please add that tag if that is the case.

Comment: What are the $u_i$??